# How do I get only the total count in Microsoft Graph query search. Is there a request to get only the total count?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

How do I get only the total count in Microsoft Graph query search. Is there a request to get only the total count?

I'm implementing a custom solution that is using MS Graph query search to get the total count results when searching SharePoint online. MS Graph API returns the total count but I'm wondering is there a way to get only the total count without retrieving hits.

API Request: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/search/query

```
{
    "value": [
        {
            "searchTerms": [
                "covid"
            ],
            "hitsContainers": [
                {
                    "hits": [...
                                ],
                    "total": 20,
                    "moreResultsAvailable": false
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(microsoft.graph.searchResponse)"
}
```

What I tried:

I used MS Graph Explorer and submitted this request
API Request: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/search/query

This is the results from MS Graph Explorer:

```
{
    "value": [
        {
            "searchTerms": [
                "covid"
            ],
            "hitsContainers": [
                {
                    "hits": [...
                                ],
                    "total": 20,
                    "moreResultsAvailable": false
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(microsoft.graph.searchResponse)"
}
```

Comment: What is the "entityTypes" in your request body?

Answer (score 1):

As per the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#count-parameter), as a query string parameter with the syntax $count=true to include a count of the total number of items in a collection alongside the page of data values returned from Microsoft Graph.  -

There is no spcefic way to get only count ,

But you can try with below Call, this will return you only 1 data ,

API - [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/?$search="displayName:Vicky"&$count=true&$top=1](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/?$search=%22displayName:Vicky%22&$count=true&$top=1)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get only total number of matching results without search results for Search API.

The response always includes `searchHitsContainer` with a collection of the search results.

Be aware of searching across `messages`, `Teams messages` and `events`, because for [messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/search-concept-messages#known-limitations), [Teams messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/search-concept-chat-messages?tabs=http#known-limitations), [events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/search-concept-events#known-limitations), `total` property of the `searchHitsContainer` type contains the number of results on the page, not the total number of matching results.